# Regex for optional leading forward slashes

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate shipping container numbers. There is an industry standard that says only alpha-numeric and 11 characters in length is acceptable. eg: FBXU8891735

However there is also a standard industry practice where the first 4 characters can be forward-slashes eg: ////8891735

I have 2 requirements - firstly to validate the container numbers (eg. matches()) and secondly to clean the container numbers (eg. replaceAll())

```
System.out.println("MSCU3720090".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}"));    //true - ok
System.out.println("////3720090".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}"));    //false - fail

System.out.println("MSCU3720090".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]*", ""));   //MSCU3720090 - ok
System.out.println("////3720090".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]*", ""));   //3720090 - fail
```

I know that for matches() I can use an alternate eg:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}|////[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}
```

However this seems ugly and I'm not sure how to use it for replaceAll().

Can someone suggest a better regex to satisfy both requirements (or one for each requirement)?

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't the requirements more specific than that?  That the first four characters (if they aren't replaced with slashes) are always letters and the rest, digits?

Comment: Yes. There is actually a whole check digit algorithm (ISO-6346), however this regex isn't trying to do that. It's just for cleaning & validating the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|/{4})[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})"
```

Then just examine the contents of capture group 1 for the number.

Comment: If you want to shorten this, \w is the same as [a-zA-Z0-9], so you could use "((?:\w{4}|/{4})\w{7})"

Comment: `\w` also matches underscores. Though you could probably use `[^\W_]`.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants a proper validation of Cargo Container Number ISO 6346, please refer [my Javascript class](https://github.com/sameersemna/Container-validator-JS) for the purpose or [Patrik Storm's PHP Class](https://github.com/stormpat/Container-validator).